# How to Pass variable to href in GenFireServerEvent to redirect url

Tags: javascript, html, xslt, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

I have a DataFormWebPart that has `<datafields> @ID,ID; </datafields>`
I want to pass this variable to the redirect url in GenFireServerEvent.

Example: `ManageView.aspx?ID=51`

```
<a href="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent(concat('__cancel;__delete={',$KeyField,'=',$KeyValue,'};__commit;__redirect={http://myportal.website.com/site/ManageView.aspx?ID=',$ID,'}'))}" onclick="return DeleteItemConfirmation();"><img src="Delete-icon.png" width="10" height="9" border="0"/></a>
```

Can someone please help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured out how to do it using xsl variable and value of.

```
<xsl:variable name="ID">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(@FileLeafRef, '-')"/>
</xsl:variable>
<a href="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent(concat('__cancel;__delete={',$KeyField,'=',$KeyValue,'};__commit;__redirect={http://myportal.website.com/site/ManageView.aspx?ID=',$ID,'}'))}" onclick="return DeleteItemConfirmation();"><img src="Delete-icon.png" width="10" height="9" border="0"/></a>
```

Great!